# Why are my kinetic energies in Coulomb field different for the states $n=2,l=0$ and $n=2,l=1$, while according to the theory they should be the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, orbital-motion, coulombs-law, hydrogen

The energy levels of motion in the Coulomb field are `E = -1/(2*n^2)`, where n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... That is, the second level from this formula has a value of -0.125. It is known from theory that each n-th level is degenerate l times (where l=1, 2, 3,..., n-1). That is, the energy level n=2,l=0 and n=2,l=1 must be the same and equal -0.125.

From the theory I know the wave functions of these states:  \
`(E^(-r/2) (1 - r/2))/Sqrt[2]` for n=2,l=0  
`(E^(-r/2) r)/(2 Sqrt[6])` for n=2,l=1

Hamiltonian of the motion in the Coulomb field: **H = -1/2 * Laplacian - 1/r**

Why do I get different energy values when they should be the same and equal to -0.125?

Wolfram Mathematica code below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Psi20[r_] := (E^(-r/2) (1 - r/2))/Sqrt[2];(*n=2, l=0*)
KK20 = -1/2*
  Integrate[
   Psi20[r]*Laplacian[Psi20[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]*
    r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
PP20 = Integrate[Psi20[r]*(-1/r)*Psi20[r]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
EE20 = KK20 + PP20

Out[1752]= -(1/8)

Psi21[r_] := (E^(-r/2) r)/(2 Sqrt[6]);(*n=2, l=1*)
KK21 = -1/2*
  Integrate[
   Psi21[r]*Laplacian[Psi21[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]*
    r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
PP21 = Integrate[Psi21[r]*(-1/r)*Psi21[r]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
EE21 = KK21 + PP21

Out[1755]= -(5/24)
```

Answer (score 3):

The hydrogen wavefunctions are three-dimensional wavefunctions.  A typical intro-quantum textbook will derive the separation of variables so that you can write

$$
\psi_{n\ell m}(r,\theta,\phi) = R_{n\ell}(r) P_\ell(\theta) F_{\ell m}(\phi)
$$

with normalized functions $R,P,F$ [somewhat easier to find online](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html) than the chapter of explanation which justifies their existence.  The products $P_\ell(\theta)F_{\ell m}(\phi) = Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$ are also called the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).

I don't quite speak Mathematica, but you seem to have set the angular wavefunctions equal to $P=F=1$, or not performed the angular integral, or both.

For what it's worth:

- I'm not sure I trust your expected energy $E=-1/8$.  You seem to be using units where the Bohr radius $a=\hbar c / \alpha mc^2=1$, but also units where $\alpha=\hbar = c = m = 1$; I'm not sure you can do all of those things at once.  The Bohr energies are $E_n = \alpha^2 mc^2 / 2n^2$.
- Relatedly, you must make sure that your wavefunctions are correctly normalized. If your probability integral $\left<\psi|\psi\right>$ doesn’t integrate to 100%, then that incorrect normalization will also affect your energy integral $\left<\psi|H|\psi\right>$. The links above include normalizations; a commenter suggests that yours are wrong.
- The degeneracy of the $n$-th level is not $\ell$, as you write, because each $\ell$ state has degeneracy $2\ell+1$.
- Physically the states $
  \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
  \ket{n\ell} = \ket{2,0} $ and $\ket{n\ell} = \ket{2,1}$ are in fact *not* degenerate, but the energy difference is small and the story is much more complicated than your question here.

Comment: In addition to the omission of the spherical harmonics for $\psi_{21}$, the OP has also neglected to normalize their states.  The first one should be a factor of 2 larger, and the second one should have the $2 \sqrt{6}$ in the denominator replaced with  $\sqrt{2}$.  If the states aren't normalized then $\langle \psi | H | \psi \rangle$ will not give the correct value for the energy.

Comment: I meant to say that and forgot; thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @rob, thank you very much for this useful answer! I have understood my mistake, it was that I did not use one more part in the kinetic energy for the state n=2, l=1, namely 1/r^2. If we take into account this part, the energies of the levels become the same.

Comment: @Michael Seifert, thanks for the comment!